# KOMA-Script: chapter headings right aligned, between horizontal lines, chapter number in words centered at top

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, tex-core

I'm using TL2023 with LyX-2.3.6.1 on Slackware64-14.2.

I'm trying to change the KOMA-Script book chapter headings so the heading is right-aligned, between two horizontal rules, and the chapter title is above the top rule as in the memoir class demo chapter head.

I had found code on the KOMA-Script wiki to place chapter headings between two lines and right-align it, but lost the code for the latter. A minimal working example preamble is below. The chapter headings are between two rules, but still left-aligned. The last two lines of the preamble show what I tried from StackExchange threads; neither works for me and I've not found code that puts the header number in lower-case words centered above the top
rule.

```
\textclass scrbook
\begin_preamble
\date{}
\usepackage{mathpazo,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,relsize}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%% Add clines above and below chaper headings
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\chapterheadstartvskip}{%
  {%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}%
      \noindent\rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par
   }\nobreak
}{%
  \typeout{Horizontal line before chapter heading added.}%
}{%
  \errmessage{Failed to patch \string\chapterheadstartvskip}%
}%
\xpretocmd{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  {%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}%
      \noindent\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par
   }\nobreak
}{%
  \typeout{Horizontal line after chapter heading added.}%
}{%
  \errmessage{Failed to patch \string\chapterheadendvskip}%
}%
%% Align chapter heading on right
%\let\raggedchapter\raggedrightrenewcommand*{\raggedsec
%%\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\raggedright}
\end_preamble
```

Pointers to solutions needed.

Answer (score 0):

Herbert Voss provided the solution on the LyX mail list:

Write into the documents preamble:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge}

\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\makebox[\linewidth]{%
\numberstringnum{\thechapter}}\\\smallskip\fi\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\smallskip\else\bigskip\fi
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedchapter\raggedleft#3}%
    \par\medskip\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}%
}%
```